# Fix duplicate data in an array with Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I request data with multiple id values. I have X amount of id values and I have them in an array.

I'm looping the `requestIdData()` function with the length of the ID array and want to save the result data into `dataDict` that the objects with id 1 are saved with one key and then objects with id 2 are saved with another key. So I'd have object array with object arrays inside it. An object array object array..

For some reason the data from all the requests with different ids are saved with the same key. So I end up having a dictionary with id array length of keys with the same data in every key..

Here's my code:

```
getIdData(): Promise<any> {
    let self = this;
    let promise: Promise<any>;

    if (this.dataDict !== {}) {
        this.dataService.getId().then(data => {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                promise = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
                    self.dataService.requestIdData(data[i])
                        .subscribe(
                        (response: any) => {
                            response.map((dataObject: { description: string, 
                            value: string }) => {
                                self.idData.push({
                                    description: dataObject.description,
                                    value: dataObject.value
                                });
                            });
                        },
                        (error: any) => console.log("error : " + error)
                        );
                    self.dataDict[i] = self.idData;
                    console.log(self.dataDict);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: You have to iterate through your response data and remove the duplicates yourself.

Comment: iterate the data with ng-repeat and from there take the individual id and work on that in controller 
http://jsbin.com/fafibeloyo/edit?html,css,js,console,output
check this URL and click on edit and check the console